# Probabilities on graphs

Tags: probability, graph-theory

Suppose we have a directed graph and each node $u$ in the graph can get infected from the environment with a probability $p_u$. Further, an infected node can transmit its infection to a neighboring node $v$ with a probability $q_{uv}$. A node can get infected either from the environment or by transmission from an infected neighboring node. Given the graph and all the probabilities $p_u$ and $q_{uv}$ for all the nodes $u$ and the arcs $uv$, can we find out what is the total probability $t_u$ that a node $u$ gets infected?

**Edit**: It is a one-shot affair. For example, if we have only one node in the graph, then $t_u = p_u$. If we have only two nodes in the graph, $u$ and $v$, and there is only an arc between $u$ to $v$. Then, $t_u = p_u$ and I think $t_v = 1 - (1-p_v)\left(p_u(1-q_{uv}) + (1-p_u)\right)$.

It seems to me that this must be a well known model or a variation of a well-known problem. Any pointers will be much appreciated.

Comment: This is not clear. Is this a one time thing or is the infection an ongoing affair?  Does an infected node stay infected forever?  If the latter than I would imagine that a single infection eventually infects the entire graph (assuming it's connected).  What would stop it?

Comment: It is a one-shot affair. For example, if we have only one node in the graph, then $t_u = p_u$. If we have only two nodes in the graph, $u$ and $v$, and there is only an arc between $u$ to $v$. Then, $t_u = p_u$ and I think $t_v = 1 - (1-p_v)\left(p_u(1-q_{uv}) + (1-p_u)\right)$.

Comment: You should edit your post to reflect this.

Comment: The complimentary event, i.e. that the node not get infected, is equivalent to saying that all the sources of infection fail independently.  That's $1-(1-p_u)\prod_v (1-q_{vu})$.

Comment: I do not think that is correct because only an infected node can transmit to its neighbor and the total probability that a node $v$ is infected, $t_v$ must feature in there? I think it will lead to a system of equations which have to be solved to figure out the $t$'s.

Comment: The $q_{vu}$ vanish if there is no edge from $v$ to $u$ (and if $v$ is infected).  Otherwise said, the product is just over the infected neighbors of the node.  I don't understand your comment about $t_v$.  At the instant of time you are considering, the nodes are either infected or they aren't.  These are initial settings, there is no probability attached to them.  Of course things change at subsequent times, but we are only meant to consider the "next" time.

Comment: Typo:  In my prior comment I meant to write that the $q_{vu}$ vanish if there is no edge from $v$ to $u$ or if $v$ is *un*infected.

Comment: Is the event of getting infected from the environment, independent of the event of getting infected from a neighboring vertex?